# Custom TrueType font not available in SSRS Report designer

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I have 2 custom fonts that were recently installed. Both fonts are True Type.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7 Enterprise.
I have a report that I need to modify so it matches our corporate standards.  The issue is, the custom fonts that were installed on my machine are unavailable in the Report Designer. Again, I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to do my report editing.

I've scoured the internet looking for a solution but still have not found one.
The fonts are available in Notepad and if I open Visual Studio and go to Tools --> Options --> Fonts and Colors. The new fonts are available.

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to get my new fonts to show up?

thank you

Comment: I got it to work.

I had to get added to the Local admin group on my development machine.

1. First Close Visual Studio if its open.

2. Then Copy the .TTF files to C:\Windows\Fonts

3. Open Visual Studio

4. Open a SSRS Report RDL in Design mode

5. Select a Textbox

6. Verify the new fonts are available